# What happens when bleachbit turns grey?

Tags: boot, apt

I just ran bleachbit as a regular user (not as root) and the progress bar at the top is stuck at "Please wait. Wiping free disk space. About 0 minutes remaining" and the entire bleachbit screen has been grey for about 5-10 minutes.

I checked APT autoclean, autoremove, and clean. I'm concerned because in the past when I ran these commands in the terminal as sudo my system wouldn't boot and I had to reinstall because I had no clue what happened or how to fix it.